# Own vector error

Tags: c++

I am trying create my own vector, I am at the beginning, and when compile e execute the code, i get "Program not responding". This is the code:

```
struct X
{
  X(){};
  ~X(){};
  int v1, v2, v3;
};

template<typename T>
class Vector
{
  public:
    // constructors
    Vector();
    Vector(unsigned s);
    virtual ~Vector();

    // overloaded operators
    T operator[](unsigned index);

    // others
    void clear();
    void add(T value);
    unsigned getSize();
    bool isEmpty();

  private:
    // pointer to first item of memory block
    T* first;
    unsigned size;
};

template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector()
{
  first = NULL;
  size = 0;
}

template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(unsigned s)
{
  size = s;
  first = new T[s];
};

template<typename T>
Vector<T>::~Vector()
{
  clear();
}

template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::clear()
{
  for(unsigned i = size ; i > 0 ; i--)
    delete &first[i];

  first = NULL;
}

template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::add(T value)
{
    T* temp = new T[size + 1]; // error happens here

    // copy data to new location
    for(unsigned i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
      temp[i] = first[i];

    // delete older data
    clear();

    // add the new value in last index
    temp[size + 1] = value;

    // update the pointer
    first = temp;

    size++;
}

template<typename T>
T Vector<T>::operator[](unsigned index)
{
  return first[index];
}

template<typename T>
unsigned Vector<T>::getSize()
{
  return size;
}

template<typename T>
bool Vector<T>::isEmpty()
{
   return first == NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
  Vector<X> anything;

  X thing;

  anything.add(thing);
  anything.add(thing);
  anything.add(thing); // if remove this line, program work fine.
}
```

As I commented, error happens in `T* temp = new T[size + 1];`.
If i define the value of `v1, v2, v3` of `X` class, e.g. `X() : v1(0), v2(0), v3(0) { }`, the program works correctly.
If i change the type, e.g., `Vector` of `int`, he works perfectly.
If put `X` class in `std::vector`, work fine too.

Other comments are also accepted.

Can someone helpme?

Comment: Have you run a test program through a debugger to see where it jams? Also why are you allocating `size + 1`?

Comment: Your `clear()` function is wrong, it should only be doing `delete[] first; first = NULL;`. A typical vector implementation would allocate a suitably sized and aligned `char` buffer, and use placement new to instantiate elements. In that case your current `clear()` implementation would be closer to what you should be doing.

Comment: Please obey: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: In addition to Praetorian's advise, following rule: You have to `delete` exactly what you `new`. That means that you don't delete things you didn't allocate with new, like the elements of your vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a buffer overflow occurring.

```
T* temp = new T[size + 1]; // When size is 0, you allocate 1 space.
```

You then assign to the temp array, but in location `temp[1]`, which isn't a valid location because your array has only 1 element. This is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and that this point, your program is free to continue however it chooses. In this case, it seems to loop indefinitely.

```
// add the new value in last index
temp[size + 1] = value; // When size is zero, your array is length '1', but
                        // you are accessing temp[1] which is outside the
                        // bounds of your allocated memory.
```

Comment: ```temp[size] = value; ``` solved the problem. Was so obvious lol. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your description of the problem is incredibly vague, but I can point out problems with your code:

- No `vector` copy constructor (causes double-deletes and crashes)
- No `vector` copy assignment (causes double-deletes and crashes)
- `clear` is incorrectly calling `delete` (causes crashes and corruption) (you should match your single `new` of an array with a single `delete` of the array.  Don't loop over elements.
- `add` is writing past the end of the array  (causes crashes and corruption)
- add is not exception safe

You have to fix at least the first four.  The third and fourth are probably the causes of your hang.